# How to keep duplicate values with most occurrence in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Let me explain, I have a dataframe like this.

I have a dataframe that contains name & country. A specific name might have more than one country. So I want to keep the name & country that occurs the most.

Input DF:

```
name    country
John       UK
John       USA
John       USA
Maria      India
Maria      India
Maria      UAE
Tim        Australia
```

Expected output:

```
name    country
John       USA
John       USA
Maria      India
Maria      India
Tim        Australia
```

Comment: In your expected output Australia is there, while UK is not. What is the reason?

Comment: `df[df['country'].eq(df.groupby('name')['country'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]))]` basically take the mode and then compare with `country` column and keep only those which matches

Comment: Are you supposed to keep the duplicates in the case where there is the same name/country combo ? e.g is it expected to have two rows of  "John, USA" ?

Comment: Sorry, I also want to keep non-duplicat evalues @Andrea...Basically remove duplicate values with less country frequency

Comment: Yeah, it is supposed to have two rows of John USA.

Comment: or also `df[df['country'].eq(df.groupby('name')['country'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]))]` either of both works

Comment: If it contain only one row of John/Maria, that is also fine, i guess.